# ink! `Mapping` default initialization

Tags: ink, storage

The [official documentation](https://ink.substrate.io/datastructures/mapping) shows this about the Mapping's initialization:

[image]

Is it fine if I initialize a Mapping using `default`?
e.g.

```
initialize_contract(|contract: &mut Self| {
   contract.my_mapping = <Mapping<T, V>>::default();
})
```

In my case, `V` is a custom struct and the goal is to have an empty mapping after the contract initialization.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine to initialize an empty `Mapping`. You can do this by not passing anything to the initialization closure.

[The docs](https://ink.substrate.io/datastructures/mapping#initializing-a-mapping) you linked to cover this default case:

```rust
#[ink(constructor)]
pub fn default() -> Self {
  // Even though we're not explicitly initializing the `Mapping`,
  // we still need to call this
  ink_lang::utils::initialize_contract(|_| {})
}
```

Comment: The docs mention here https://use.ink/ink-vs-solidity/#mapping-declaration mention that when using a map in ink! we must to use `ink_lang::utils::initialize_contract` in the constructor and provides a link to https://use.ink/datastructures/mapping/ for more details, but that link doesn't actually show any further details about using `initialize_contract`, it simply shows an example of initialising the contract with an empty mapping in the constructor `let balances = Mapping::default();`.

Comment: So do we still need to use `ink_lang::utils::initialize_contract(|_| {})` like you've shown above to cover the `fn default()` case? Or do we just explicitly set variables to mapping defaults with `Mapping::default()` in `fn new()` instead now?

Comment: It seems we still need to use `ink_lang::utils::initialize_contract(|_| {})` since it is shown in an example here https://use.ink/ink-vs-solidity/#nested-mappings--custom--advanced-structures